# writing regular expression with constraints

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

I am working on a JavaScript regular expression for the following condition check.

*Consignment number validation details:*

- Cnote length :12 Varchar
- First Character should be Character Upper Case
- Fifth Character may be character or integer
- Remaining all integer

Examples of valid strings:

```
C991S1234567
C30811234567
```

I have no idea. I have tried a simple regular expression like checking only numbers or alphabets.

I have tried something like this:

```
^[0-9]
```

It allows only integers. I do not know how to add constraints to it. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Still, please post what you have tried. Also, what about the 2nd, 3rd and 4th characters? Should they always be digits?

Comment: Yes sir.. As point 4 says remaining all should be integers.

Comment: So what expressions did you try? I have an answer for you, but I need to know what you tried to better understand what exactly was missing there.

Comment: Sir i do not have much idea about Regex. I have tried something this ^[0-9]. But of course it allows only integers. I do not know how to add constraints to it.

Comment: Please do comment and ask if something sounds unclear.

Comment: Was there something about the basic regexp tutorial or documentation you studied (you did, right?) that was so hard to understand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The regex for this task relies on [character classes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) (`[...]`) and [limiting quantifiers](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#limit) (`{n}`). `^[0-9]` only checks if the first character is a digit.

You can use the following regex:

```
^[A-Z][0-9]{3}[a-zA-Z0-9][0-9]{7}$
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/tO3uZ3/2)

**Explanation**:

- `^` - Beginning of the string
- `[A-Z]` - First is an uppercase English letter
- `[0-9]{3}` - The 2nd, 3rd and 4th characters are digits
- `[a-zA-Z0-9]` - Fifth character is either a letter or digit
- `[0-9]{7}` - Following 7 characters are digits
- `$` - End of string.